# Override vim autocmd for Makefiles

Tags: vim

A class I'm taking requires code to be submitted with two spaces instead of tab characters. I have an autocmd in `.vimrc` to use two space long tabs only within the directory used for the assignments in that class.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ~/path/to/dir/* set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
```

However, I don't want Makefiles in the directory to use the `expandtab` option since make requires tab characters.

To do this I created another autocmd in `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab
```

However, while the first autocmd works great, the second will not override the first and `expandtab` will continue to be set, even on Makefiles or files of type make. This happens regardless of order in the config.

One somewhat hack-y solution I've found to work is to use

```
autocmd FileType make autocmd!
```

which disables all other autocmd's for the file. However, this will disable ALL other autocmd's for Makefiles, which is undesirable.

Is there any other way to give the second command priority over the first, or somehow disable the `expandtab` option on Makefiles?

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting is generally a lot easier than blacklisting:

```
augroup class
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ~/path/to/dir/*.{foo,bar,baz} set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the configuration in `~/.vim/filetype.vim` instead of `~/.vimrc`, it might already work, because then your user customization runs *before* the built-in `ftplugin/Makefile` (which resets the indent settings to something sensible):

```
augroup filetypedetect
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ~/path/to/dir/* set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
augroup END
```

If that doesn't work, I would add a conditional to the `:autocmd` instead of defining a neutralizing second `:autocmd`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ~/path/to/dir/* if &filetype !=# 'make' | set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using one autocmd on `FileType` and the other on `BufNewFile,BufRead` events is that the event type [determines the order in which autocmds are executed](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/what-is-the-order-of-winenter-bufenter-bufread-syntax-filetype-events), though this order isn't very well defined.

I chose to use the same event types for both autocmds. This way the order in which they are specified is the order in which they run (as the vim docs state, though without mentioning the event type caveat):

```
set noexpandtab

au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter /some/path/* set expandtab

" Not using FileType since that seems to run before BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter
au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter *.go set noexpandtab
```

The filetype detection for makefiles is probably defined somewhere in terms of autocmds with event types such as `BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter`, so maybe you can copy those rules into your `.vimrc` and use the same event types for your other rule (perhaps not the cleanest solution).